# Can’t find the php.ini file in XAMPP

Tags: php, configuration, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP and now I want to change some settings in the `php.ini` file, but I can’t find it anywhere. Instead, in the `xampp/php` directory I found two files: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. Can I use these in order to do the changes I want?

Comment: `echo phpinfo()` to find out what php.ini is included

Comment: You rename one of them to be your `php.ini` file.  They give you both as examples.

Comment: according to phpinfo() the path for the configuration file is C:\\Windows but it's not there.

Comment: actually, i think i got it finally....thanks anyway

Comment: It would be nice is you left the solution here, @dimitris012. At least as a comment. Questions and answers here on [SO] are supposed to help not only the original poster, but also all the people who come from search engines or stumble upon it when browsing the site.

Comment: @DimitrisChousiadas how did you find php.ini file?

Answer (score 2):

php.ini is hidden by Default. You need to show it using CP folder settings

Comment: What are CP folder settings in windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
Important Configuration Files And Directories

opt/lampp/bin/ - The XAMPP commands home. /opt/lampp/bin/mysql calls for example the MySQL monitor. 

/opt/lampp/htdocs/ - The Apache DocumentRoot directory. 

/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf - The Apache configuration file. 

/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf - The MySQL configuration file. 

/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini - The PHP configuration file. 

/opt/lampp/etc/proftpd.conf - The ProFTPD configuration file. (since 0.9.5) 

/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php - The phpMyAdmin configuration file.
```